# "Sending to cluster" issue using a Spark cluster in Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

I want to run a cell in the Databricks notebook but I'm receiving the message "Sending to cluster" without end. I ran the same cell before without issues. I restarted the cluster and I have the same issue.

[image]

Also, I tested with different code and I have the same problem:
[image]

Comment: For starters, that queey is shown half way.  Second, what cluser are you referring to? Third, how can we re-create that db? ddl?

Comment: try checking if you have the same problem on another, preferably fresh, cluster. we had a similar issue on Azure Databricks and resolved it by creating a new cluster.

Comment: At the end the problem was fixed itself a while later

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what Marat said, create a new cluster but also give appropriate resources to the cluster - may be more than whatever you have given right now.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to set up  a little worksheet frame like print("hello") and it came back. Go to the worksheet cell that is the problem. Detach. Go to cluster and ensure its stopped.  Go to worksheet and insert a row above where the stuck point is.  Then attach it to a cluster.

Type in print("Hello") (python) and press run.  See if that makes it come back fairly immediately.

If so, when it comes back, then try running the problem cell which should be the next one below.

Before that I've tried:
A) Stoping and restarting the cluster.
B) Switching to a different cluster
C) Creating a new cluster.

But it just stays in this "Sending to Cluster" state and it stayed that way for hours.  See if that helps. If anyone has an additional selection that worked for them, please link it here.  Thanks!